# The HTML Validation result is 93 errors and 22 warnings

Tags: html, w3c-validation

To check for the HTML Validation when i insert my url i get this error msg

Comment: Congratulations, now you can start fixing them.

Answer (score 1):

This means you have a lot of problems, so your HTML is **not valid**.

Read the error messages and fix the problems in your markup until you have 0 errors.